# Implementing a login system (max login tries, IP checks, etc.)

Tags: php, authentication

What are the most important elements to implement in a login program in php?

I already know of a lot of things to do, but I would be interested in a concrete way / correct order to implement those (and other things if I might have missed something).

- Captchas after some login attempts
- Locking of an user account after too many tries (reactivation via email autentication)
- Dynamically increasing waiting time after false attempts for an IP address (?)
- Decreasing this time-span again with time
- (Short-term) blocking of IP addresses if really necessary (either automatically or per admin who is notified of drastically increased login attempts from a certain IP)
- Releasing IPs (also admin or automatically after some time)

(Of course password strength is checked on registration, and HTTPS is used to authenticate)

So first of all: Are there things/checks/steps that also need to be taken?
And secondly: What would be a suitable concrete implementation of this program.

This is what I would have started off with (very simplified):

```
    function onLoginTry($name, $pass)
    {
        // Following checks exit the script if necessary
        check_if_ip_is_blocked(); // also possibly unblock if time has come
        check_if_user_is_locked();
        check_if_captcha_is_used_if_needed();

        // Correct Login
        if (login_ok($name, $pass))
        { 
            login($name);
        }

        // False Login
        else
        {
            // Check here for number of tries so far etc (from DB)
            // ...
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Simply blocking a user account for x minutes after x attempts is usually enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, but while you have typed a lot, there seems to be some room for effort here. You have started out ok I guess, but you both have a long list of abstract things you consider (you maybe want feedback on all of them?) and then you come with some pseudo code, sure. But you expect implementations of `check_if_ip_is_blocked()` ? Why not show us where you are stuck? This looks like this will be a big never-ending book-like-question/answer. My advice would be to split your question into real, isolated, answerable questions.

Comment: @user574632: I agree that this might suffice in most cases, albeit since I am looking at a rather sensible application I can't allow a single device (repeatedly) blocking all users by trying passwords for example (since here no IP check is applied).

Comment: @Nanne: I do not need you to write out functions like `check_if_ip_is_blocked()` or any of the others, quite the opposite I am looking for a good / working program structure which can just call some functions like this but in fact deals with the mentioned problems. (So I am more or less only looking for what belongs into the `else` block, in the same way the rest is structured)

Comment: I am not so much interested in the concrete implementation of functions (it would be easy to implement/finetune those), but rather the pattern(s) on the higher level.

Comment: Also could the "close voters" explain what is too broad here? It is a simple programming pattern with a code example (given to avoid being too broad) that needs to be completed.

Answer (score 1):

Locking IP's and users based on bad attempts is usually a bad thing, Your blocking people through what can be no fault of their own (if i try admin/root 100X i lock you out).
I usually do the following

Record the attempted user and IP address.
If more than x login attempts in y minutes (which is set by you and can scale, I usually start with 5 attempts in 30 minutes) then show a captcha.

These are tracked independently of each other, So 5 IP attempts on 5 accounts would work just as well as 5 ips on 1 user account.

I usually also check the global fails, ie if there have been more than 100 failed attempts in an hour, all users are required to enter a captcha. This stops against people using 1 password against many usernames (for example `hunter2` against all valid user accounts)

This way doesnt lock people out, it only asks for extra  information. I would recommend using an existing third party captcha than trying to implement your own

Comment: I really like the 5 attempts in 30 minutes (separately for users and IPs)! But won't that be already enough, to stop someone to try out one single password for all users - unless I only have 5 users ^^

Comment: No, IP's are fairly cheap to come by, Some botnets may have 100's of ip's.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you are getting at! I am not so much concerned about them changing IPs that much, although some distributed attack might be able to do that :-/ ... still it might be difficult to differenciate between a very busy day (with probably a lot of idiots not remembering their passwords) and an actual attack :-/

Comment: You changed your comment, tricky ^^ I agree, but still the question how to differenciate there, ...

Comment: Yeah sorry - i mis understood what you were asking. Scale the 100 with the users. Mine is 100 and ive not hit that limit (or been to close to it) with over 1000 users. Its not a magic number, just what works best

Comment: Probably could scale that automatically with the user base, and for example make it a multiple of the number of registered users. I like that, it's always the easy ideas - like scale it - that get me, thx :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tough security, always use your own methods. Doing what public do will make the attacker knows your system. Then they doesn't need to guess so many things since they know what you have.

Also for this question, here people will say you most famous things. So I don't think you really made it with a tough security.

Comment: Thats a GOOD thing, If the attacker knows the system and still cant get in, Your secure. Your method relys on Security_through_obscurity